# Django - USStateField vs USZipCodeField

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-forms

Why is one of these a model and the other is a form?  For example, in order to get it to behave correctly this is my model:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    state = USStateField()
    zip = models.CharField(max_length=30)
```

and this is my form:

```
class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    zip = USZipCodeField()
```

I would think that it would make sense for their to be a USZipCodeField model so that the code is symmetric

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you probably just want to use [`USStateField`](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/localflavor/#django.contrib.localflavor.us.forms.USStateField) directly:

```
from django.contrib.localflavor.us.forms import USStateField

class UserProfileForm(forms.ModelForm):
    state = USStateField()
    zip = USZipCodeField()
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
```

Is there a reason you were using `USZipCodeField` for your `zip` field, but `forms.ChoiceField` for your state?

Comment: USStateField() just makes an empty textbox.  It's not even a dropdown

Comment: state = USStateField(widget=USStateSelect) works but there's no blank option

Comment: i fixed the original issue but i've revised the question